# Is it possible to use Traefik to proxy PostgreSQL over SSL?

Tags: postgresql, tcp, proxy, traefik, sni

#### Motivations

I am a running into an issue when trying to proxy PostgreSQL with Traefik over SSL using Let's Encrypt.
I did some research but it is not well documented and I would like to confirm my observations and leave a record to everyone who faces this situation.

#### Configuration

I use latest versions of PostgreSQL v12 and Traefik v2. I want to build a **pure TCP flow** from `tcp://example.com:5432` -> `tcp://postgresql:5432` over TLS using Let's Encrypt.

Traefik service is configured as follow:

```yaml
  version: "3.6"
    
    services:
    
      traefik:
        image: traefik:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
          - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
          - "./configuration/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml:ro"
          - "./configuration/dynamic_conf.toml:/etc/traefik/dynamic_conf.toml"
          - "./letsencrypt/acme.json:/acme.json"
    
        networks:
          - backend
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
          - "5432:5432"
    
    networks:
      backend:
        external: true
```

With the static setup:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http]
      [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
        to = "websecure"
        scheme = "https"

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.websecure.http]
      [entryPoints.websecure.http.tls]
        certresolver = "lets"

  [entryPoints.postgres]
    address = ":5432"
```

PostgreSQL service is configured as follow:

```yaml
version: "3.6"

services:

  postgresql:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/trial_config.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf:ro
      - ./configuration/trial_hba.conf:/etc/postgresql/pg_hba.conf:ro
      - ./configuration/initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - postgresql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - backend
    #ports:
    #  - 5432:5432
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=backend"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.entrypoints=postgres"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.rule=HostSNI(`example.com`)"
      - "traefic.tcp.routers.postgres.tls=true"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.tls.certresolver=lets"
      - "traefik.tcp.services.postgres.loadBalancer.server.port=5432"

networks:
  backend:
    external: true

volumes:
  postgresql-data:
```

It seems my Traefik configuration is correct. Everything is OK in the logs and all sections in dashboard are flagged as Success (no Warnings, no Errors). So I am confident with the Traefik configuration above. The complete flow is about:

```
EntryPoint(':5432') -> HostSNI(`example.com`) -> TcpRouter(`postgres`) -> Service(`postgres@docker`)
```

But, it may have a limitation at PostgreSQL side.

#### Debug

The problem is that I cannot connect the PostgreSQL database. I always get a **Timeout error**.

I have checked PostgreSQL is listening properly (main cause of Timeout error):

```
# - Connection Settings -
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

And I checked that I can connect PostgreSQL on the host (outside the container):

```sh
psql --host 172.19.0.4 -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql (12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4), server 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Thus I know PostgreSQL is listening outside its container, so Traefik should be able to bind the flow.
I also have checked external traefik can reach the server:

```sh
sudo tcpdump -i ens3 port 5432
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:02:37.878614 IP x.y-z-w.isp.com.61229 > example.com.postgresql: Flags [S], seq 1027429527, win 64240, options [mss 1452,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:02:37.879858 IP example.com.postgresql > x.y-z-w.isp.com.61229: Flags [S.], seq 3545496818, ack 1027429528, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:02:37.922591 IP x.y-z-w.isp.com.61229 > example.com.postgresql: Flags [.], ack 1, win 516, length 0
09:02:37.922718 IP x.y-z-w.isp.com.61229 > example.com.postgresql: Flags [P.], seq 1:9, ack 1, win 516, length 8
09:02:37.922750 IP example.com.postgresql > x.y-z-w.isp.com.61229: Flags [.], ack 9, win 502, length 0
09:02:47.908808 IP x.y-z-w.isp.com.61229 > example.com.postgresql: Flags [F.], seq 9, ack 1, win 516, length 0
09:02:47.909578 IP example.com.postgresql > x.y-z-w.isp.com.61229: Flags [P.], seq 1:104, ack 10, win 502, length 103
09:02:47.909754 IP example.com.postgresql > x.y-z-w.isp.com.61229: Flags [F.], seq 104, ack 10, win 502, length 0
09:02:47.961826 IP x.y-z-w.isp.com.61229 > example.com.postgresql: Flags [R.], seq 10, ack 104, win 0, length 0
```

So, I am wondering why the connection cannot succeed. Something must be wrong between Traefik and PostgreSQL.

#### SNI incompatibility?

Even when I remove the TLS configuration, the problem is still there, so I don't expect the TLS to be the origin of this problem.

Then I searched and I found few posts relating similar issue:

- [Introducing SNI in TLS handshake for SSL connections](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/d05341b9-033f-d5fe-966e-889f5f9218e5%40proxel.se)
- [Traefik 2.0 TCP routing for multiple DBs](https://www.reddit.com/r/Traefik/comments/dwjrnu/traefik_20_tcp_routing_for_multiple_dbs/);

As far as I understand it, the SSL protocol of PostgreSQL is a custom one and does not support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) for now and might never support it. If it is correct, it will confirm that Traefik cannot proxy PostgreSQL for now and this is a limitation.

By writing this post I would like to confirm my observations and at the same time leave a visible record on Stack Overflow to anyone who faces the same problem and seek for help. My question is then: **Is it possible to use Traefik to proxy PostgreSQL?**

**Update**

Intersting observation, if using `HostSNI('*')` and Let's Encrypt:

```yaml
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=backend"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.entrypoints=postgres"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.rule=HostSNI(`*`)"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.tls=true"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.tls.certresolver=lets"
      - "traefik.tcp.services.postgres.loadBalancer.server.port=5432"
```

Everything is flagged as success in Dashboard but of course Let's Encrypt cannot perform the DNS Challenge for wildcard `*`, it complaints in logs:

```sh
time="2020-08-12T10:25:22Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"*\": unable to generate a wildcard certificate in ACME provider for domain \"*\" : ACME needs a DNSChallenge" providerName=lets.acme routerName=postgres@docker rule="HostSNI(`*`)"
```

When I try the following configuration:

```yaml
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=backend"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.entrypoints=postgres"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.rule=HostSNI(`*`)"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.tls=true"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.tls.domains[0].main=example.com"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.tls.certresolver=lets"
      - "traefik.tcp.services.postgres.loadBalancer.server.port=5432"
```

The error vanishes from logs and in both setups the dashboard seems ok but traffic is not routed to PostgreSQL (time out). Anyway, removing SSL from the configuration makes the flow complete (and unsecure):

```yaml
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=backend"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.entrypoints=postgres"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.rule=HostSNI(`*`)"
      - "traefik.tcp.services.postgres.loadBalancer.server.port=5432"
```

Then it is possible to connect PostgreSQL database:

```sh
time="2020-08-12T10:30:52Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from x.y.z.w:58389"
```

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't talk http at all because... it isn't a web server. So - can this "traefik" thing route plain tcp like haproxy can?

Comment: @RichardHuxton, to my understanding: Yes, the "traefik" thing does fully support TCP which precedes HTTP if both rules exist (see https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#configuring-tcp-routers). In my configuration you can check that this is pure TCP not HTTP.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know traefik at all, but the TLS stuff on the postgres router doesn't make sense to me. If you are just forwarding tcp, why would you be fiddling with that?

Comment: @RichardHuxton, Well I don't want to expose the postgresql port in clear over the web (after all credentials are sent though this flow) and I would like to withdraw the TLS configuration from postgresql then Traefik and Let's Encrypt can take it in charge automatically. On the other hand, even if I remove the TLS configuration, the traffic is not routed either way which seems to be related to the SNI issue.

Comment: Did you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: @khashashin, not yet. I think the only workaround from now is to cypher PSQL connexion as usual and setup Traefik to let SSL pass through. But then you loose the benefit of LE.

Comment: can you post answer to this if you found a solution?

Comment: STARTTLS support has been added to Traefik in this (https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/9377) PR. This makes Traefik wait for Postgres to send the TLS headers first before routing the request. I was able to deploy multiple postgres databases with subdomains with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SNI routing for postgres with STARTTLS has been added to Traefik in [this](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/9377) PR. Now Treafik will listen to the initial bytes sent by postgres and if its going to initiate a TLS handshake (Note that postgres TLS requests are created as non-TLS first and then upgraded to TLS requests), Treafik will handle the handshake and then is able to receive the TLS headers from postgres, which contains the SNI information that it needs to route the request properly. This means that you can use `HostSNI("example.com")` along with tls to expose postgres databases under different subdomains.

As of writing this answer, I was able to get this working with the `v3.0.0-beta2` image ([Reference](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/issues/757#issuecomment-1366135192))

Comment: Thanks @sreeram-venkitesh I was trying out same, it is not working for me, I have shared the details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77202096/using-traefik-v3-and-postgres-with-tls-ingress can you help me if I am missing something ?

Answer (score 5):

IMPORTANT: This feature only works on Traefik v3.0 onwards.

I could make it work properly with the following labels in my postgres docker compose:

```
labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.tcp.routers.postgresql.rule=HostSNI(`sub.domain.com`)
  - traefik.tcp.routers.postgresql.tls=true
  - traefik.tcp.services.postgresql.loadbalancer.server.port=5432
  - traefik.tcp.routers.postgresql.entrypoints=dbsecure
  - traefik.tcp.routers.postgresql.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
```

While my traefik already had a configuration to add SSL certificates with let's encrypt for HTTPS, so to make it work with the postgres database I only added the following command as part of the configuration:

```
- --entrypoints.dbsecure.address=:5432
```

Comment: Thanks @leadvic I was trying out same, it is not working for me, I have shared the details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77202096/using-traefik-v3-and-postgres-with-tls-ingress can you help me if I am missing something ?

Comment: I can confirm this works with Traefik 3.0 beta 3, postgres 16, and the DBeaver database client (java-based)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Traefik to proxy PostgreSQL, so answer is yes. But I'm not using TLS, because my setup is a bit different. First of all, if PostgreSQL doesn't support SNI, then I would suggest to try to modify labels, especially HostSNI rule to this:

```
"traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.rule=HostSNI(`*`)"
```

That says: ignore SNI and just take any name from specified entrypoint as valid.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I did test it but with SSL enabled and it does not worked. But if removing SSL, then the flow is complete. I have updated my post accordingly. Any chance you have another idea to implement SSL, if not I will need to resort to PostgreSQL SSL config and pass_trough switch. Best regards,

Comment: for the TLS I think the problem is with lets encrypt, since you don't have SNI, you can't have certificate without domain name... but it seems there is possibility to define domain name with router, see https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#domains_1 -- maybe you will need DNS challenge with wildcard domain name

Comment: Thank you for your help, not yet working but it is progressing. I did have a try with domains, the error about * vanishes but Traefik does not route to PostgreSQL an ymore. I have updated my post to reflect the test.

Comment: @dmaixner and @`op` have you found a way to enable TLS with postgreSQL ? What PG Version are you using ?

Comment: lets say i want to have like 10 postgresql databases, how will the setup look like if i need to setup TCP for all 10 and connect to each separately at same time?